# Spring Data Specification Join by specific field

Tags: java, jpa, join, outer-join, criteria-api

I have a Join looking like:

```
Join<RepairEntity, RepairAssignEntity> joinRepairAssignEntities = root.join(RepairEntity_.repairAssignEntities, LEFT);
```

when it converted to SQL it looks like

```
left outer join
        repair_assign repairassi1_ 
            on repairenti0_.id=repairassi1_.repair_id
```

I want it to be like:

```
left outer join
        repair_assign repairassi1_ 
            on repairenti0_.PARENT_ID=repairassi1_.repair_id
```

If I add condition to that join:

```
Predicate equal = cb.equal(root.get(RepairEntity_.parentId), repairEntityPath.get(RepairEntity_.id));
joinRepairAssignEntities = joinRepairAssignEntities.on(equal);
```

it makes it

```
left outer join
        repair_assign repairassi1_ 
            on repairenti0_.id=repairassi1_.repair_id 
            and (
                repairenti0_.parent_id=repairassi1_.repair_id
            )
```

How do I get rid of

```
on repairenti0_.id=repairassi1_.repair_id
```

?

Answer (score 0):

A priori it seems that the entities are not well related, if you want to join by the parent field it should be something like this:

Entity RepairEntity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
RepairAssignEntity repairAssignEntity;
```

Entity RepairAssignEntity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="repairAssignEntity", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
List<RepairEntity> RepairEntities;
```

if not, you would have to restructure the query to adapt it to the JPA entity modeling.

Regarding to get rid of the condition "on repairenti0_.id = repairassi1_.repair_id" you cannot because it is the implicit one of the relationship defined in the entity, but if you modify the modeling as I indicate, only the condition "repairenti0_.parent_id = repairassi1_ will appear. .repair_id "